# Can't log out of chat

Tags: support, status-completed, chat, logout

I've occasionally used my sister's computer to visit stackexchange sites, including the chat on EL&U. This was all well and good, except that tonight, my sister decided she wanted to join the fun and get an account of her own.

Well, let's just say that "not fun" (and "not easy") don't even begin to cover it. Apparently, it wasn't enough for *her* to hit "log out everywhere"<sup>1</sup> on her computer, ***I*** had to do the same on *my* computer. Which is creepy. And then I had to press an ominous-sounding "destroy credentials" button. But anyway.

Even after logging out of everything stackexchange related I could find, *I'm still logged in to EL&U chat*. And there's no logout button on chat. There's a "leave (all)", but that doesn't actually log you out, it just leaves the room(s) you're in.

Is there a way to log out of chat? If so, where is it hiding?

<sup>1</sup> [A misnomer if ever there was one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73702/what-does-log-out-everywhere-actually-do-and-what-is-it-supposed-to-do)

Comment: I just found this question.  For what it's worth, I eventually got it using the links below, but the logging out process is an absolute disaster. I'm on a communal computer in my office, and many of use multiple SE sites as well as chat. Hopefully this will be improved, because it's still a total hassle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The logout pages for the chat sites are located at:

https://chat.stackexchange.com/logout  <--You want this one
http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/logout
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/logout
http://chat.serverfault.com/logout
http://chat.superuser.com/logout

These links are not accessible from the chat sites, for some reason or other which I can't remember.

Comment: Where did you find out about these links, by the way? Is there a sooper-seekrit chat user manual hidden somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

When we next deploy, your regular SE logout button will also log you out from chat.SE