# Chat logout not linked to Stack Exchange logout?

Tags: support, status-completed, chat, logout

I just did a global logout and 'destroy credentials' on [stackexchange.com](http://stackexchange.com) but found myself still logged in to chat. Repro steps:

1. Close chat and all trilogy/SE tabs
2. Global SE logout and destroy credentials
3. Restart browser
4. Visit chat

Is this intended? I can't see a way to log out of chat without deleting cookies.

Edit: This may be a dupe of [Can't log out of chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80935/cant-log-out-of-chat) but that's been marked as answered and I'd argue there is still an issue here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fully working after the next deploy.